# jQuery Document Ready and Function Scope

Tags: jquery

I want to provide helper functions that allow various components of a complex jQuery-based UI to hide or show a loading *div* (used when an Ajax call is initiated from various portions of the page).

To that end, I initially wrote code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function ()
{
    var loadingControl = $("#loading");

    function showLoading() {
        loadingControl.show();
    }
}
</script>
```

However, I quickly realized that *showLoading* is only in scope within that particular *document ready*.

Following the advice from

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1055799/141172

I declared *showLoading* in global scope like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var showLoading;
$(function ()
{
    var loadingControl = $("#loading");

    function showLoading() {
        loadingControl.show();
    }
}
</script>
```

However, I still find that *showLoading* is not available in *document ready* blocks that execute later.  The error is

> The value of the property 'showLoading' is null or undefined, not a Function object

This behavior can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/NfXFT/4/

The jsFiddle also proves that the *showLoading* implementation's *document ready* runs before the *document ready* block that calls it.

What is going wrong, and how can I make this helper method available?

I define it within a *document ready* block because it relies on '#loading' being available.  Is there a better approach to accomplishing the same goal of providing a helper function to hide/show the loading screen?  I want to keep this in a helper function because the implementation may change later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right after posting, I realized what I had done wrong.

```
function showLoading() {
    loadingControl.show();
}
```

should be

```
showLoading = function() {
    loadingControl.show();
}
```