# coffeescript : defining callbacks before they're called

Tags: node.js, callback, coffeescript

I'm writing a basic node.js web server in coffeescript. When I write:

```
server.listen(3000, listener)
listener = () ->
  console.log 'server listening on port 3000'
```

It starts the server, but doesn't print the message. So I gather that the callback isn't being called. On the other hand, when I do:

```
listener = () ->
  console.log 'server listening on port 3000'
server.listen(3000, listener)
```

the message is printed on the console.

Why does the callback get called if it's defined before the call, but not if it's defined afterwards?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname. CoffeeScript does not generate named functions (outside of classes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the way CoffeeScript function definitions work, your first snippet is equivalent to something like this in JavaScript:

```
var message;
console.log(message()); // message is undefined at this point
message = function() { return "Hello World!"; };
```

`message` doesn't exist when it is first accessed, so this throws an error. It sounds like you want:

```
console.log(message());
function message() { return "Hello World!"; }
```

Which works fine, but AFAIK, there is no way to write that in CoffeeScript.

Comment: yep, i was about to link http://stackoverflow.com/a/16549446/1375688, but yeah you're right.

Comment: The `var listener` happens before the `server.listen` call and the `listener = function() { ... }` happens after. So `listener` does exist (or the JavaScript engine would give you a ReferenceError) but its value is `undefined` so they're actually doing `server.listen(3000, undefined)`. So you're on the right track but the details are a bit off.