# AngularJS function hoisting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a 'beginner' question. Why does this error out? I call the function in the code, but the function is defined further down.

AngularJS version:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Someone';
    $scope.doStuff(); // run the defined function, but errors out

    $scope.doStuff= function(){  // function definition
        console.log('did something');
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2fjuJ/4/

But this one works fine:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Someone';
    $scope.doStuff = function(){
        console.log('did something');
    }

    $scope.doStuff(); 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2fjuJ/5/

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439949/define-local-function-in-javascript-use-var-or-not

Comment: thank you. I'll definitely read this.

Comment: Also this: http://designpepper.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting

Comment: doStuff is not hoisted the way you've written it; change it to function doStuff and it should get hoisted and not cause an error

Comment: This is what you should *really* be reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not declaring a new variable when you write $scope.doStuff = function () {...}, you're assigning a property, which does not get hoisted. at the time you call $scope.doStuff(), $scope looks like:

```
{
    name: "Someone"
}
```

As you can see there's no "doStuff" property until the next line executes.

Comment: What has declaring variables to do with that?

Comment: simple enough. was hoping for a solution to remedy this, but the explanation is clear enough.