# Problems with David Shariff's JavaScript Quiz

Tags: javascript

Some help needed with the [Quiz](http://davidshariff.com/js-quiz/#q=5):

**Question 5:**

```
function bar() {
    return foo;
    foo = 10;
    function foo() {}
    var foo = '11';
}
alert(typeof bar());
```

Q: What is alerted?
A: function.

Based on this [tutorial](http://javascript.info/tutorial/initialization), even it does not say that clearly and this is probably my misinterpretation, I was expecting the following behavior, when `bar()` gets called:

1. Function `foo()` added to the lexical environment of `bar()`.
2. `var foo = '11';` overrides this definition, leaving `foo` undefined.
3. When `return foo;` is executed, `foo` is undefined.

What happens in the initialization? Any links for good documentation?

**Question 12:**

```
String('Hello') === 'Hello';
```

Q: what is the result?
A: true.

I thought `String()` would return an object and `'Hello'` is a primitive string, thus the answer would be "false". Why is it "true"?

**Question 20:**

```
NaN === NaN;
```

Q: what is the result?
A: false.

What is the logic? What happens here?

Comment: In the future it is preferable to ask and research one question at a time rather than multiple questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 5:

This is because of hoisting, I answer this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23889317/explain-this-javascript-name-clash/23889367#23889367) in more detail.

```
function bar() {
    return foo;
    foo = 10;
    function foo() {}
    var foo = '11';
}
```

Is semantically the same as:

```
function bar() {
    var foo = function(){}; // function declarations and 
                           // variable declarations are hoisted
    return foo;
    foo = 10;
    foo = '11';
}
```

Question 12:

Calling `String` on something as a function does not create a new object. Note it is not called as a constructor:

```
String("a"); // a primitive value type string "a"
new String("a"); // this creates a new string object
```

Quoting [the specification](http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.1):

> When String is called as part of a new expression, it is a constructor: it initialises the newly created object.

Question 20:

Pretty much because the specification says so. `NaN` is not equal to anything, including itself. The rationale is not to get two miscalculations equal to each other by mistake.

Comment: Question 5: I understand hoisting, but what happens with the variable initialization? Is it simply so that because `foo` is already defined, `var foo = '11'` does not undefine it?

Comment: @masa yes, precisely. `var a = 10; var a;console.log(a)` logs 10

Answer (score 1):

I've done a video series of javascript in which I'm explaining David Sharrif's all javascript questions. Have a look at this playlist:

[Solutions: David Sharrif Quiz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6V-eHaj3ow&list=PLYxzS__5yYQlwfMje_MxQPb18tXtCJbfR&index=30)