# Why variable appears undefined outside document ready tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope

I have observed a strange behavior while learning jQuery and Javascript. When I call a variable that is defined inside the $(document).ready, from outside these tags it appears undefined, even when I define it as a global variable,
For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   myVar = "test";
});
alert(typeof(myVar));
//Results "undefined"
```

If I call the same variable inside the document.ready tags it works as expected

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   myVar = "test";
   alert(typeof(myVar));
   //Results "String"
});
```

The result is same even after using window prefix.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   window.myVar = "test";
});
alert(typeof(window.myVar));
//Results "undefined"
```

I understand about the variable scopes but why even global variables aren't working this way. I am so confused.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4363155/4790490) post

Answer (score 3):

The code inside the "ready" handler will not run until the DOM has been fully built. The code *outside* the handler will run as soon as it is encountered. Thus, your `alert()` runs *before* the code in the handler runs, so the outcome makes perfect sense: the global variable has not yet been initialized, so its value is `undefined`.

You can see the sequence of execution clearly by putting `alert()` (or, better, `console.log()`) calls inside the "ready" handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("In the 'ready' handler");
});
console.log("Outside the 'ready' handler");
```

When that runs, you'll see the "Outside" message logged *first*.

Comment: Perfect explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Because the `alert()` is executed before your document is perfectly ready.. You may try even by declaring the variable before `$(document).ready()` still it will return undefined..

Answer (score 0):

The $(document).ready() gets fired after the page is fully loaded

When the script tag is fully loaded the alert gets executed.

So

1. Script tag is loaded => Execute alert
2. Continue loading page
3. Page completly loaded => fire $(document).ready
4. You var is getting set

The alert gets executed before your var is set

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct but it is probably important to also note the `$(document).ready(...)` is also hiding your variable from the global scope. You could declare your variable then update it within the function

```
var myVar;

$(document).ready(function() {
    myVar = "test";
});

console.log(myVar)   // test
```

Comment: No, since the variable is referenced in the function without a `var` declaration. It's implicitly global.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I have been reading up on scopes and jumped at the question without fully thinking it through. :-) I assume the reason I cannot recreate this in a fiddle is because the JSFiddle wrapper document is ready before executing any code?

Comment: The default setup in jsfiddle is for your code to be run in a window "load" handler - it's controllable via the JavaScript options. Click the little "gear" icon in the upper-right corner of the JavaScript panel.

Answer (score 0):

The execution plan it's like

```
//this statement shall fix the driver, not run it
$(document).ready(function() {//-->this it's an event handler waiting to be fired when content is fully loaded
   myVar = "test";//-->myVar won't exists until this event is triggered
});
//this execute the alert function but myVar not exist yet
alert(typeof(myVar));
```

**$(document).ready()** is like to assign an event who will execute after the content is loaded, which means **alert(myVar)** will run before the lambda execution which was set as the content-loaded event. I hope you'll understand me.