# Function wrapped in jQuery not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scope

I have a function in the script tag that initializes a couple of scripts in a separate file called "filters.js". But for some reason it returns "initialize is not defined". Does wrapping the function in jQuery change the scope? Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/filters.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>ICTV Filters</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="filterCategory">
        <div class="categoryTitle">
            Genome
            <input type="checkbox" id="ssDNA" />
            <label for="ssDNA">ssDNA</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="dsDNA" />
            <label for="dsDNA">dsDNA</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="ssRNA" />
            <label for="ssRNA">ssRNA</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="dsRNA" />
            <label for="dsRNA">dsRNA</label>
            <button onclick="initialize()">Apply Filters</button> <!-- Returns error on this line-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="filterReturn">
        <p id="filterReplace"></p>
    </div>

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            function initialize() {
                getSelections();
                updateObject();
                updateLocalStorage();
                $(document).trigger('filtersUpdated');
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"Does wrapping the function in jQuery change the scope? "_ You seem to already know your answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363113/jquery-scope-inside-document-ready

Comment: Is filters.js depends on jQuery?

Comment: Define the `initialize()` function outside of the jQuery function and call it from within...

Comment: @S1awek Yes, filters.js uses jQuery.

Comment: @j08691 I thought that might be the problem but I had the function outside of the jQuery before and it returned the same error.

Comment: @DJN So  `<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>` has to be on the top of `<script src="Scripts/filters.js"></script>`

Comment: @S1awek Although this did not fix the error, thank you for pointing that out.